# How to counts "Y" in Row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

How to counts "y" value in python and update this output new column.

Example:-
col 3 to col 7 find the value "y" and update the counts the last col.

like this image.

[image]

Comment: add sample code

Comment: instead of an image post `df.to_dict()` of df construction code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are looking to calculate all the 'Y' in row-wise level then you can use the below condition:

```
df['counts']=(df == 'Y').sum(axis=1)
```

if you want to mention specific columns then u can use the below condition:

```
df['counts']=(df[['INR','USA','UK','SA','ENG']]=='Y').sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First filter string columns:

```
# filter object columns
cols = list(filter(lambda x: df[x].dtype == 'object', df.columns))
```

Then, count the number of `Y` and sum across the row

```
y_count = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.count('Y')).sum(axis=1)
```

Finally, assign to the new column as `counts`

```
df = df.assign(counts = y_count)
print(df)
```